# WCF - adding service tag leads to 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, web-config

I have a web service. I am using an svc file (WSIntegrationEpis.svc), with the following content:

```
<% @ServiceHost Service="XXX.YYY.WSIntegration.EPis.WSEPis" %>
```

If I have nothing in system.serviceModel in my web.config the web service works fine.
However once I try to add the service tag the server starts to return `415 Unsupported Media Type`

The content of the service tag:

```
<services>
  <service name="XXX.YYY.WSIntegration.EPis.WSEPis"  behaviorConfiguration="EPis.WSEPis.DefaultBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="XXX.YYY.WSIntegration.EPis.IWSEPis"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

The behavior section is standard one:

```
    <behavior name="EPis.WSEPis.DefaultBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
```

Notes:

1/ If I rename the name of the service (so the names in svc and service tag are different), the WS starts working.

2/ If I remove the behaviorConfiguration attribute form the service tag it still does not work.

3/ If I add `bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IWSEPis"` as attribute to service tag (and in binding I specify correct binding configuration), the web service stilll does nto work.

What I should change so that I will be bale to specify parameters in the web.config for my web.service?

Answer (score -2):

Please check is your service name matched with your class name it case-sensitive.